# Excel counting without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to figure out how to count how many times a name pops up within a week, per day. However, I dont want duplicates if their name shows up multiple times within that day. People are signing up under which resources they will be using that day.

| Day | Pen | Pencil | Eraser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Joshua | Joshua | Carla |
| Tuesday | Joshua | Carla |  |

I tried using countif but it would count the duplicates as well.

Example: Looking at Monday. Excel would count joshua as 2, but I only want him counted as 1.

So then that week, if we only count that there’s Monday and Tuesday in a week. Joshua should result as 2, not 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(IF(B2:D3="",NA(),A2:A3),3),
     b,TOCOL(B2:D3,1),
     c,DROP(UNIQUE(HSTACK(a,b)),,1),
     d,UNIQUE(c),
     HSTACK(d,MMULT(N(d=TOROW(c)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(c),,,0))))
```

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the **Power Query** window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Day"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Day", "Value"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Value"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Value", "Names"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(data=name),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0))>=1))`

This requires the `SEQUENCE` function (ie use of a dynamic array version of Excel).

`data` is the array of names (so the array of 2 rows and 3 columns obtained by excluding the header row and header column of   the table showing in the OP).

`name` is the name  being sought eg "Joshua".

**Explanation:**

`N(data=name)` creates an array the same size as `data` of 0's and 1's, with a 1 meaning that `name` is in array `data` in the corresponding position. 0 means `name` is not in the corresponding position.

`SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0)` creates an array with just 1 column and the same number of rows as there are columns in `data`. Each element of the array has the value of 1.

`MMULT(N(data=name),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0)` multiplies the two arrays together using [matrix multiplication](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html). The choice of the second array means that the result of this is to create an array with the same number of rows as `data` and just 1 column. The elements of this result count the number of times  that `name` appears in the corresponding row of `data`.

Adding, `>=1` and wrapping the result inside the `N()` function, converts the results array to 1's and 0's with a 1 if `name` appears in the corresponding row of `data` and 0 otherwise. Wrapping the whole thing in the `SUM` function gives the required result for `name`.

**Note:**

If a dynamic version of Excel is not available then the column array of 1's created by the `SEQUENCE` function can be replaced by a range on the worksheet which is 1 column wide and has the same number of rows as there are columns in data. All the elements in the range should be 1. This range can be substituted for the `SEQUENCE` function in the formula, though it may require the use of Ctl+Shift+Enter for entering the final formula as an array formula. Both the `MMULT` and `COLUMNS` functions are available in older, non-dynamic array versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

### Count By Row Using REDUCE/XMATCH

[image]

```
=LET(data,B2:D8,
    u,UNIQUE(TOCOL(data,3)),
    Names,FILTER(u,u<>""),
    Zeros,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Names),,0,0),
    RowIndices,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    Counts,REDUCE(Zeros,RowIndices,LAMBDA(Result,r,
        Result+ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Names,INDEX(data,r,))))),
    dr,HSTACK(Names,Counts),
dr)
```

- If you put the data in an Excel table, you could e.g. use

  ```
  =LET(data,Drop(Table1,,1),...
  ```